# mongodb aggregation php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongodb 2.1 and how to translate this query into php

```
db.counter.aggregate([ 
 { $match:{ page_id:123456 }}, 
 { $group:{_id:"$page_id",total:{$sum:"$pageview"}} } 
 ]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the 'command()' method in PHP to run the aggregation framework as a database command.  The precise syntax for your sample query would be:

```
   $conn = new Mongo("localhost:$port");
   $db = $conn->test;

   $result = $db->command (
            array( 
                "aggregate" => "counter",
                "pipeline" => 
                    array( 
                        array( '$match' => array( 'page_id' => 123456 )),
                        array( '$group' => array( "_id" => '$page_id',
                                    'total' => array( '$sum' => '$pageview')  
                                )
                            )
                    )
            )
        );
```

Comment: An [aggregate()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php) helper has been added in the 1.3.0 `mongo` driver.  The underlying `command()` syntax still works, too :).

Comment: I also tried like this for my query. But it is returning an error which says  exception: wrong type for field (aggregate) 3 != 2

Comment: @Alwin: this means that you have a syntax error.  There's no way to know what it is without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$con = $m->selectDB("dbName")->selectCollection("counter");
$cond = array(
    array('$match' => array('page_id' =>123456)),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$page_id',
           'total' => array('$sum' => '$pageview'),
        ),
    )
);
$out = $con->aggregate($cond);
print_r($out);
```

For more detail [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php)